# Unexpected drop in UFW noise, should I be worried?

Tags: firewalls, logging, intrusion

I run a bare-metal on-premises GitLab server (Ubuntu 22.04) for a very small company. While the server isn't currently in *production* use, it is active and accessible over the public internet.

I have UFW set to block everything except HTTP, HTTPS, and remapped SSH port. The SSH port logs all connections. Since making the server internet-facing, I've been seeing repeated hits, UFW blocking and logging any bots knocking on these ports. Every day I check for these hits with `journalctl -b0 --grep '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'`. There's usually about 10-15 `[UFW BLOCK]` entries per day from these bots. This noise is normal, part of being visible to the public internet.

However, this past week or so I've noticed the number of hits dropped significantly. I still get `[UFW BLOCK]` entries, but now it's down to 3-5 per day, and usually from only one or two IPs. This could just be fewer bots poking the server, but it might be someone having gotten in and hiding their entrance.

I'm worried that this is the sign of an intruder cleaning up logs after themselves. I don't have remote logging (or a dedicated machine that could receive logs), though I do have PAM email me every time someone (other than user `git`) logs in with SSH. UFW rules don't appear to be modified. Should I be worried?

Comment: This is impossible to tell. It is not even clear what exact rules you have which log. 10..15 attempts per day sounds very low for me for an internet connected system in the first place.

Comment: By default UFW logs anything blocked unless there's a rule for it. I have rules allowing ports for HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH. HTTP/HTTPS are unlogged unless blocked. SSH is set to log even on allowed connections. Anything that gets blocked is logged, except for multicast noise from the router.

If 10-15 was already very low I don't know what to tell you. That was what I was getting before, and now I'm getting much less. For that reason I'm concerned.

Comment: Given the few block's you see on a single day your system is either in a  quiet area of the internet or your provider is already blocking some traffic.